# Transparency with circles

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl

I am drawing a circle using two triangles and the fragment shader. I can get a nice looking circle to draw in the middle of the square formed by the triangles, but for some reason the circle is surrounded by the remaining white triangles and is not transparent. I want the edges to be transparent, so that two circles would overlay each other nicely.

Here is my fragment shader code:

```
void main() {
    float diff = 1.0 / vscale.x;
    float dist = distance(center, origin);
    float step = smoothstep(radius - diff, radius + diff, dist);

    gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), step);
}
```

[image: Bad circles]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words, and Stack Overflow makes it ***really*** easy to upload screenshots. That said, I think what you are describing is a lack of or incorrect blending between the fragments generated by the two primitives.

Comment: i actually didnt know that. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @andon-m-coleman said, i had a lack of blending between fragments. i didnt know i had to set a blendfunc. thanks!

EDIT: that is to say, i did not set a blend function, like this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: @mdml i just edited it to provide a code example. how about now?